# BeautifulSoup is returning the whole html instead of what i've selected

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Really new to this, so this might be a non-issue but I can't find anything on it. My code outputs the whole html rather then what i've set to return.

I've been fixing the issues I ran into but this one I can't seem to find anything on.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
soup =
BeautifulSoup(open("Watch List.html", encoding='utf-8'), 'html.parser')

section = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'content'})
results = section.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'item watching'})+section.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'item watched'})
results = soup.prettify().splitlines()
print(results)
```

Comment: The second last line should be `results = results.prettify().splitlines()`.

Comment: But `results.prettify()` will throw an error as `results` is a list. You will have to loop over the list elements.

Comment: What is `soup.prettify()` meant to do?

Comment: cleans up the output to make it better to read

Comment: so removing "results = soup.prettify().splitlines()" and just printing the results gave me what I wanted, but the output is unreadable. So I guess my problem now is prettify

Comment: Of course it will return your whole html, since you're overwriting the `results` with `soup.prettify()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it entirely wrong!!! 
In BeautifulSoup, `find()` returns a single element while `find_all()` returns a list, even if the list only contains one item. In your code,

```
section.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'item watching'})
```

is supposed to return a list which is concatenated with your second `find_all` which is

```
section.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'item watched'})
```

which is also supposed to throw a list, but it won't since you are doing it wrong. It should be `soup.find_all()` instead of `section.find_all()` since `section` is not the initialised object while `soup` is.

And for the final part, `soup.prettify()` will return the whole page of course, since you set the parser there.

Your code should look like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("Watch List.html", encoding='utf-8'), 'html.parser')
# soup.find() returns a single element
section = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'content'})
# this will print out the <div class="content" ...>
print(section)
# soup.find_all() returns a list
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'item watching'})+soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'item watched'}) 
# the above line returns a list, so you'll have to iterate it over:
for result in results:
    res = result.prettify()
    # prints out prettified stuff one by one
    print(res)
    # print(res+"\n\n")
```

Comment: I was trying to take a section of the soup (hince the name) then try to search through that with .find_all. I wanted all the items with the id of "item watching" and "item watched" and then assign those as "results". Is this the wrong way of narrowing my workspace in the html?

Comment: First of all, programming doesn't work like that, you could assign a variable name `lol` to something which isn't even funny. Second, You should have a look at the docs before using any library. Third, you didn't do anything wrong, it was just the logic and your way of interpretation which was wrong.

Comment: I named it "section" not because I assumed it would magicaly give a section of the soup but because it made sense with what result I was going for. Then I wanted "results" only out of the "section" that I just searched.